# WP Contact form is not working, Spinning wheel forever after submitting form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I have created a contact form on our website, I thought it worked in the past, but now when you click the submit button nothing happens and a blue spinning wheel comes up and nothing happens.

Does anyone know what it can be? Some manage to fix it by deleting the password-protect plugin but I do not have that enabled.

[Java error from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbIwG.png)

Link to the website with the contact form: https://www.hamarbilpleie.no/kontakt-oss/

[Dubug plugin result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9cpz.png)

```
[03-Mar-2021 20:31:48 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Function get_magic_quotes_gpc() is deprecated in /home/2/h/hamarbilpleie/www/wp-content/themes/carservice/contact_form.php on line 261 

[03-Mar-2021 20:31:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to cs_phpmailer_init() must be an instance of PHPMailer, instance of PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer given, called in /home/2/h/hamarbilpleie/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287 and defined in /home/2/h/hamarbilpleie/www/wp-content/themes/carservice/functions.php:298 Stack trace:
#0 /home/2/h/hamarbilpleie/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): cs_phpmailer_init(Object(PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer))
#1 /home/2/h/hamarbilpleie/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#2 /home/2/h/hamarbilpleie/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(551): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /home/2/h/hamarbilpleie/www/wp-includes/pluggable.php(494): do_action_ref_array('phpmailer_init', Array)
#4 /home/2/h/hamarbilpleie/www/wp-content/themes/carservice/contact_form.php(280): wp_mail(Array, 'Foresp\xC3\xB8rsel fr...', 'F\xC3\xB8lgende henve...', Array)
#5 /home/2/h/hamarbilpleie/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): cs_theme_contact_form('')
#6 /home/2/h/hamarbilple in /home/2/h/hamarbilpleie/www/wp-content/themes/carservice/functions.php on line 298
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are having a bug in Javascript. What you have to do is, open up the Developer Tools in your browser, then goto **Console** tab. You would find the error messages there. Copy that error and share it with us.

[image]

[image]

---

**EDIT**

I can see that there's a 500 Internal Server Error (based on the screenshot you provided) when the data is submitted to the server. What you have to do is, see if there's any error log created inside your server. It would have some information regarding what is causing the issue. Please share it with us. If you are not able to see it, please follow this: [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/)

---

**EDIT 2**

It appears that you are having two issues in your theme's `functions.php` file. It's using one depreciated function and for the other probably because of old code. The line numbers are `#261` and `#298` (`/wp-content/themes/carservice/functions.php`). The easy would be to ask your theme developer to get it fixed for you. If you have the update available for your theme and plugins, make sure you update it. Kindly note that, if you have done any modifications on the `functions.php` file, instead of doing it in a child theme, those changes would be overwritten when you update the theme.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the replay, I just added a picture in the main post.

Comment: @Jan-petterHavna I have edited my answer. Please check.

Comment: Hi, 
I do not have access to the server, I'm using the web-based wp, but i installed the debug plugin. will add that as picutre above

Comment: @Jan-petterHavna What you have shown in screenshot doesn't show what we actually needed! Can you please try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/error-log-monitor/ It would show a widget in the Admin Dashboard. It would show the error logs.

Comment: Sorry, I can't install that plugin. It tells me to do and edit a file,, but I do not have any FTP access as far as i know.

Comment: I got in the back end now, will get the error log for you soon.

Comment: Hi, 

I just added what I got when I tried to use the contact form and checked the debug.log after activate the debug

Comment: Thanks for your help and patient. I tried to contact the theme developer, and they told me that the issue was not with them.  But I do agree with you that there is a fault in their code. I have also made sure we have the latest version.

Comment: @Jan-petterHavna no problem. It's clearly the developer's problem as their code is for an older PHP version. One solution (not the recommended one) would be to downgrade the PHP on your server to an older version. If you visit Tools --> Site Health, you would be able to see the current version. And your server might have multiple PHP installations. You can ask them to downgrade the PHP or if you can access the cPanel, you could do this easily using the `Multi PHP Manager`. Or else, try creating a new question here, with the code from #261 to 298 and the error message. We will see if can help.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging and discussion, I found out that the theme had not been updated for ages. But to find an update for this was not easy. For some reason, it did not automatically update from WP. But it is fixed now. Thanks for the tips and hints, guys.